# Anaconda "import georaster" error: specified module not found

Tags: python, dll, anaconda, gdal

I am using Anaconda3 5.2.0 for Windows 10 64 bit, which is python 3.6.5 (Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe). I have installed this into C:\Anaconda3 and then from the anaconda prompt installed basemap:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-files
```

I have used this to start building map files and everything is working fine. I then wanted to add a raster to the map using georaster.

```
conda install -c conda-forge georaster
```

This also installs gdal.

When I open Jupyter Notebook and enter the line

```
import georaster
```

I get the following error message:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I have tried various solutions that I have seen for related issues including installing a gdal update, fiona, and geopandas. None of these change the message.

I tried installing gdal using the binaries .whl file in conda, but despite following the advice (which said to use pip) I was not able to make it work.

```
pip install GDAL-2.2.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

resulted in an error message:

> GDAL-2.2.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Finally I went looking to see if I could locate the missing DLL manually. I saw one user suggest libtiff.dll was the missing file, and indeed it was one I did not have. I downloaded it and copied it into the System32 and SysWOW64 folders. This still resulted in an error but changed the error message:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

However I could not find a way to stop the error from occurring. I followed the steps to register the .dll but that also had an error message from not found to not supported:

(cmd prompt in administrator mode)

```
regsvr32.exe /i libtiff.dll
```

> The module "libtiff.dll" failed to load.
>
> Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files.
>
> The specified module could not be found.

I have tried downloading from 2 other websites, neither with any success. It is feeling like every method I attempt now just hits some weird error that nobody else is seeming to have and I don't understand why.

If anyone could offer some advice I'd be very appreciative. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Issue resolved. The problem was that the GDAL import in conda-forge was not adding all the specified files only the wrapper. Even going and installing the .msi was not doing this properly.

To fix go to this page:

http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php

And then instead of downloading and installing the core, download the binaries. In the /bin folder copy all the DLLs and then paste them into /lib/site-packages/choose-a-module (I picked osgeo). Then also paste them into /DLLs to get jupyter notebook to see it. This will make the error message go away.

Oh, and thanks for the downvote

Answer (score 0):

downloading the required *.whl file(GDAL-2.2.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl) from  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal and then copying it to a location like C:\GDAL-2.2.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

then pip install c:\GDAL-2.2.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

worked for me.

Thanks.